# React Native - OnPress button not working

Tags: react-native

I have a button with a onPress event i am trying to simply console log that the button was successfully pressed.

The button is within my template file i have extracted this portion of code to a separate file, ive done the same for my tyles.

The add() function associated with the press does not fire when i press the add button, so the console.log does not show.

But the console.log does does show on initial load of the screen ( i dont know why this is )

**items.screen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import style from './items.style'
import template from './items.template';

export default class ItemsScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Items"
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: '' };
    }

    add() {
        console.log("pressed add button");
    }


    render() {
        return template(this, style);
    }

}
```

**items.template.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { style } from './items.style'

export default (template, style) => {
    return (
        <View style={style.container}>
            <TextInput
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                value={template.state.text}
                onChangeText={(text) => template.setState({ text })}
            />

            <Button
                onPress={template.add()}
                title="Add"
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: try this:
<Button
                onPress={() => {template.add()}}
                title="Add"
            />

Comment: @Li357 how? can you provide an example for me to learn from

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning `template.add` to the on press event, instead your code is executing the `add` function and attempting to assign the result of that to the `onPress` event.

I find the following two options to be cleaner than the other suggestions:

Create a local `onPress` Handler (in `items.template`)

```
onPress = () => {
  template.add();
}
```

and then

```
onPress={this.onPress} //note the lack of parentheses `()`
```

**or**

create an inline function

```
onPress={() => template.add()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass function in attribute,not function call, so it should be

```
        <Button
            onPress={template.add.bind(template)}
            title="Add"
        />
```

Comment: how would this work if i wanted to pass some variables into the add function

Comment: Just add it after bind target (template in this example). For example template.add.bind(template, someValue). You can read more about bind function here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Hmm this seems like a really messy solution. instead of passing in "this" and "style" is it possible for my template file to know these values?

Comment: Your style of coding react components is kinda unusual, usually you render components and pass props, I.e. Styles. In this case I'd recommend rewrite items component as React component and pass all needed in props, like you were passing onPress to Button, rewrite items component and pass style, onAdd to props and use it in component, instead of calling template function.

Comment: ye i am new, do you mind showing me this method in a paste bin?